# How to output Contentful text as HTML instead of a string in Gatsby?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, contentful

I can't get a long text field in Contenful to output properly in Gatsby.

I've tried:

```js
const ProjectPost = ({ data }) => {
  const { title, body } = data.contentfulProject
  return (
    <Layout>
      <SEO title={title} />
      <div className="blogpost">
        <h1>{title}</h1>
        <div>{body.body}</div>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default ProjectPost

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query($slug: String!) {
    contentfulProject(slug: { eq: $slug }) {
      title
      slug
      body {
        body
      }
    }
  }
`
```

that {body.body} outputs the content without any markup. It's just a few paragraphs of wrapped in quotes.

If I do:

```js
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import SEO from "../components/seo"

const ProjectPost = ({ data }) => {
  const { title, body } = data.contentfulProject
  return (
    <Layout>
      <SEO title={title} />
      <div className="blogpost">
        <h1>{title}</h1>
        <div>{body.childMarkdownRemark.html}</div>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default ProjectPost

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query($slug: String!) {
    contentfulProject(slug: { eq: $slug }) {
      title
      slug
      body {
        childMarkdownRemark {
          html
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

it outputs HTML wrapped in quotes, but isn't parsed as HTML in the browser. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are certain security issues around inserting HTML directly from a CMS into a React component, but if you are satisfied that your setup is sufficiently secure you could use the special `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` React attribute which takes a string of HTML and converts it into actual markup.

Use this wisely and take a moment to read up on some of the security issues here, but replacing your `<div>` with the following should display the actual HTML from your CMS.

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: body.childMarkdownRemark.html }}></div>
```

Comment: thank you! I've been researching this since last night and came across: @contentful/rich-text-react-renderer. I've installed that and can successfully output the rich text with '<div>{documentToReactComponents(project.description.json)}</div>' - I assume if it's an official way of doing it from Contentful, it should be secure?

Comment: Ah if Contentful have their own more elegant way of handling this then yes, I would advise to use that. This is a generic solution that I’ve used a few times for other HTML sources!